# What are some security problems with my code?

Tags: c, security, passwords

Just a simple username/password authenticator. Everything is working fine, but I'm trying to improve the security of this code and remove any vulnerabilities. What can I do to ensure there are no flaws?

Ignore the init() function, its just temporary for now and will be implemented later.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define USRLEN 9
#define IDTABSIZE 256
#define FOLDERNAMELEN 256 //A filename can be no longer than 256chars in Linux FS

typedef char USER[USRLEN];
typedef unsigned char UID;

USER uidTable[IDTABSIZE];

UID userCount;

void init(void){
  userCount=3;
  strcpy(uidTable[0],"user");
  passwordAdd("bla",0); 
  strcpy(uidTable[1],"student");
  passwordAdd("OK",1);
  strcpy(uidTable[2],"admin123");
  passwordAdd("Str0ng_w3_ar3",2);

}

UID findId(char* usr){
  int i=userCount;
  while((i--) && (strncmp(usr,uidTable[i],8)))
    ;
    return i; 
}

int authenticate(char * user, char * password){
  PASSWORD passwd; 
  UID uid;
  strcpy(passwd,password);
  uid=findId(user);
  return (passwordVerify(passwd,uid)); 
}

int main(int argc, char*argv[]){
  char folderName[FOLDERNAMELEN+1]; //Last one for \0 
  char command[FOLDERNAMELEN + 8]; //String to keep mkdir folderName
  int count;
  char inpChar;

  init();

  if (argc!=3){
    printf("Wrong number of parameters!!!\n");
    printf("USAGE %s username password\n",argv[0]);
    printf("username is up to %d characters\n",USRLEN-1);
    printf("password is up to %d characters.\n",PASSLEN-1);
    printf("Allows an authenticated user to create a new mail folder\n");
    exit(-1);
  }

  if (!authenticate(argv[1],argv[2]))
  {
    printf("SORRY we can not accept your credentials!!\n");
    exit(-2);
  }
  printf("Please enter the name of the mail folder:");
  count=-1;
  do{
    scanf("%c",&inpChar);
    count++;
    folderName[count]=inpChar;   
  } while(count<FOLDERNAMELEN && folderName[count]!='\n');
  folderName[count]='\0';
  strcpy(command,"mkdir ");
  strcat(command,folderName);
  system(command);
}
```

Ignore the init() function, its just temporary for now and will be implemented later.

Comment: Possibly a better question for [codereview.se] or [security.se] or [softwareengineering.se].

Comment: the most obvious - you are not checking the input length before copying it to local buffers

Comment: You have no control over the length of `argv[2]`, yet you `strcpy()` it to a fixed length array with no checking.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network - https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya While this may be on-topic on CR, in the future, please don't use the existence of the Code Review site as a reason to close a question. Evaluate the request and use a reason like *Needs more focus* (as I have done here), *primarily opinion-based*, etc. Please see [_Does being on-topic at another Stack Exchange site automatically make a question off-topic for Stack Overflow?_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287400/1575353)

Comment: `PASSWORD passwd;` then `strcpy(passwd,password);` is completely sensless. Either PASSWORD is a typedef for an array in which case you need to get rid of that bad typedef. Or it's a struct or similar, in which case the code doesn't make sense and won't compile. You seem to have similar ugly typedefs and global variables all over.